# How do I list objects on a dropdown and the properties of the objects to a table in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have data from API where I need to put the object keys in a dropdown list. The properties of the selected list should render on a table such that when a user selects an option, the table repopulates with data for the option selected.

data looks like....below

```
{
  "all_facilities": {
    "General Hospital": [
      {
        "date": "2022-09-02 22:38:48",
        "facility_id": 222,
        "facility_name": "Mike's hospital",
        "hmo_name": "NJC",
        "member_gender": "",
        "member_id": "8000000001",
        "member_name": "Test",
      }
    ],
    "Clinic": [
      {
       "date": "2022-09-02 22:38:48",
        "facility_id": 222,
        "facility_name": "Mike's hospital",
        "hmo_name": "NJC",
        "member_gender": "",
        "member_id": "8000000001",
        "member_name": "Test",
      },
      {
       "date": "2022-09-02 22:38:48",
        "facility_id": 222,
        "facility_name": "Mike's hospital",
        "hmo_name": "NJC",
        "member_gender": "",
        "member_id": "8000000001",
        "member_name": "Test",
      }
    ],
    "PHC": [
      {
        "date": "2022-09-02 22:38:48",
        "facility_id": 222,
        "facility_name": "Mike's hospital",
        "hmo_name": "NJC",
        "member_gender": "",
        "member_id": "8000000001",
        "member_name": "Test",
      },
      {
       
        "date": "2022-09-02 22:38:48",
        "facility_id": 222,
        "facility_name": "Mike's hospital",
        "hmo_name": "NJC",
        "member_gender": "",
        "member_id": "8000000001",
        "member_name": "Test",
       
      }
    ]
  },
  
}
```

I'm really confused how best to approach this to put the keys General,PHC,Clinic in a dropdown and the props of selected key in a table. I really need help

Comment: you can use `Object.keys` for getting value from it as a keys but i am not understanding the flow for saving data in table.

Comment: Are you using any library for the dropdown and table?